# Computations to omit from $M^TM$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to find M the the the corresponding matrix to the diagonal of S. M consists of S's eigenvectors.  $$S= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&0 \\ 2&2&1 \\ 0&1&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Which i found. but now it says i have to calculate $M^TM$ with as little computation as possible and give reasons for computation i was able to omit. What does that mean!!!!

Is it that $M^TM$ is symmetrical such that $M^TM=MM^T$ so maybe i could save time by multiplying it the other way around?

Comment: I see $S$. Where is $M$?

Comment: Whatever $M$ is, $M^TM$ is symmetric, but that doesn't mean that $M^TM=MM^T$, which is a very different property that depends on $M$.

Comment: M is the matrix corresponding to the diagonal of M

Comment: M consists of S's eigenvectors.

Comment: If you choose those eigenvectors to be real orthonormal vectors, then $M^TM$ will be very easy to compute.  You can do so because $S$ is real symmetric.

Comment: Please tell me more? How can i make something orthonormal!

Comment: The eigenvalues of $S$ are distinct, hence the eigenvectors are orthogonal. They are easy to normalise - just divide by the norm. So you may assume that $M$ is an orthogonal matrix, and, as @JonasMeyer pointed out, it is trivial to compute $M^T M$.

Comment: If $M^{-1}=M^{T}$ then $M^{T}M=A$?

Comment: What do you mean by very easy to compute? Is there at trick $M^TM$ for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @Ivan: Look up the definition of orthogonal matrix, and the definition of inverse matrix.  (And what is $A$?)